# Firestore plugin causing build error for Flutter Android App

Tags: firebase, flutter

Trying to setup cloud_firestore in my Flutter project, and it loads fine for iOS. However, the build is failing for Android with the error:

```
FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':app:transformDexArchiveWithExternalLibsDexMergerForDebug'.
> java.lang.RuntimeException: java.lang.RuntimeException: com.android.builder.dexing.DexArchiveMergerException: Unable to merge dex
```

In my pubspec.yaml I have:

```
cloud_firestore: ^0.8.2+3
```

I added this classpath to android/build.gradle:

```
classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:4.0.1'
```

And this to app/build.gradle:

```
apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
```

I believe I have done everything correctly in the Android setup for Firestore, but it still will not work. Any idea why it won't build for Android?